# More smooth CSS animation

Tags: css

So I have this wave animation, but when it restarts its very noticeable. Is there a way to make this animation more smooth, so it just loops, without noticing that it restarted the animation?

Here is the wave animation:

```css
/* for the pen */
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* waves */
.ocean {
  height: 80px; /* change the height of the waves here */
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wave {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 800 88.7'%3E%3Cpath d='M800 56.9c-155.5 0-204.9-50-405.5-49.9-200 0-250 49.9-394.5 49.9v31.8h800v-.2-31.6z' fill='%23003F7C'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: wave 10s -3s linear infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wave 18s linear reverse infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.wave:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wave 20s -1s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@keyframes wave {
    0% {transform: translateX(0);}
    50% {transform: translateX(-25%);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-50%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="ocean">
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** start the animation and wait a little while looking at it, and you will see the restart of the animation is not smooth. The three waves restarts at three different times, 10s, 18s and 20s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another **@Keyframe** and update time duration in CSS. I just update all changes in below code snippet and I hope it'll help you out. Thank You

```css
/* for the pen */
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* waves */
.ocean {
  height: 80px; /* change the height of the waves here */
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wave {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 800 88.7'%3E%3Cpath d='M800 56.9c-155.5 0-204.9-50-405.5-49.9-200 0-250 49.9-394.5 49.9v31.8h800v-.2-31.6z' fill='%23003F7C'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: wave 15s -3s linear infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wave 20s linear reverse infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.wave:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wave 25s -1s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@keyframes wave {
    0% {transform: translateX(0);}
    25% {transform: translateX(-25%);}
    50% {transform: translateX(-50%);}
    75% {transform: translateX(-25%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="ocean">
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>
```